# XMLWorkerHelper to convert a long html into pdf produces only first page

Tags: itext

I am using following code to convert a long html and want the pdf to span multiple A4 pages depending on the length of the source html. But it only produces first pdf page for first part of the html text that fits the A4 page. Using itextsharp 5.4.0

Source HTML is something like this

```
<html><body><table><tr><td>
<p> Para 1 -lorem ipsum ..... </p>
......
<p> Para 100 - loren ipsum .... </p>
</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

C# code is

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 70, 55, 40, 25);
string sFileName = "output.pdf";
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Create));
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
pdfDocument.Open();
StreamReader fw = new StreamReader("D:\\sample\\avfs.html");
string htmlText = fw.ReadToEnd();
fw.Close();
XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(wri, pdfDocument, new StringReader(htmlText));
pdfDocument.Close();
```

Comment: Did you find the solution. I'm facing the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(**PageSize.LETTER**, 70, 55, 40, 25);
```

**instead of**

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document(**PageSize.A4**, 70, 55, 40, 25);
```